# Angular Reset Paginator

Tags: angular, angular7, material

Estoy intentando ir a la primera página del mat-paginator, es decir, resetear la paginación, pero no funciona. ¿Alguna idea de como se puede solucionar?

el html es tal que así:

```
        <mat-paginator [length]="itemTotal" [pageIndex]="page" [pageSize]="itemPage" (page)="pageEvent = getPublicationFollowersData($event)">
        </mat-paginator>
```

El typescript:

```
    getPublicationFollowersData(event?: PageEvent) {
          this.getPublicationsUser(event.pageIndex);
    }
```

e intento inicializar la página con:

```
this.page =1
```

pero no funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Declara el elemento `#paginador`

```
<mat-paginator [length]="itemTotal" [pageIndex]="page" [pageSize]="itemPage"  #paginador>
 </mat-paginator>
```

Luego lo delcaras en el componente:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginador: MatPaginator;
```

Desde alguna función tuya propia, llamas a la funcion `firstPage()` para a la primera pagina:

```
nuevaFuncion() {
         this.paginator.firstPage();
}
```

Comment: Gracias @ivan.depi me ha funcionado correctamente